# Wordpress: how to install an app to work alongside wordpress

Tags: regex, wordpress, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'd like to install an app to work alongside wordpress so that

All urls go to wordpress and this one goes to my app www.example.com/myapp.

I'me guessing i'll need to change the .htaccess file/

Thanks you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can install your app in a subdirectory e.g. `myapp/` and make sure to add this rule as the **first rule** in our wordpress's `.htaccess` file:

```
# skip myapp/ from Wordpress's rules
RewriteRule ^myapp(/|$) - [L,NC]
```

Comment: Do you know how to modify this so it has a wildcard of directories after the myapp directory?

Comment: Sure it is very much possible but if you can clarify what you're trying to do I can edit my answer.

Comment: I'm trying to achieve this /myapp/* but atm it takes me to the wordpres 404 page.

Comment: You can use: `RewriteRule ^myapp/.* - [L,NC]`

Answer (score 1):

just create a directory "myapp" in the installation directory of your wordpress installation and put your files in there.